# Using enumerate on a generator to parse text

Tags: python, generator, enumerate

I'm trying to iterate over a text file (containing several stories) and return a list of lists where each list is a new story.

- read_lines_in_text(fname) is a generator that I want to iterate over to read each line in the text file. This must remain a generator.
- find_title(fname) is a function that must be used and returns a list of the lines in the text where a title appears (and therefore signals the start of a new story).

The code I have written below does the job, but I think it is not a great solution.

```
newdict = {}
story = []
list_of_stories = []

for idx, line in enumerate(read_lines_in_text(fname)):
    if line in find_title(fname):
        newdict[idx] = line

for idx, line in enumerate(read_lines_in_text(fname)):
    if idx >= list(newdict.keys())[0]:
        if idx in newdict:
            list_of_stories.append(story)
            story = []
            story.append(line)
        else:
            story.append(line)
```

Given than I have the indexes of where each title occurs in the text, I want to have something like the following:

```
for lines between key i and key i+1 in mydict:
append to story
list_of_stories.append(story)
story = []
```

Comment: Note: your `list(newdict.keys())[0]` test would only work in Python 3.6 or newer where dictionaries happen to list keys in insertion order. Any earlier Python version is likely to give you the wrong index value there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use indices at all. Just *start a new `story` list whenever you have a new title*, and append the previous one to `list_of_stories`:

```
story = []
list_of_stories = []
titles = set(find_title(fname))

for line in read_lines_in_text(fname):
    if line in titles:
        # start a new story, append the previous
        if story:
            list_of_stories.append(story)
        story = [line]
    elif story:  # a story has been started
        story.append(line)

# handle the last story
if story:
    list_of_stories.append(story)
```

When using a generator function, you really want to *avoid* treating it as a random access sequence with index numbers.

Note that we also avoid reading `fname` more than once just to get the titles; the `titles` variable is a set of title strings returned by `find_title()`, stored as a set for fast membership testing.